# Help with basic step of solving Heat Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm working on the beginnings of solving the partial differential heat equation using method of separation of variables. There's a basic step I need clarified that I can't find a full explanation to in my textbooks. Please bear with me as I give a rough explanation before stating my question.

I'm solving the heat equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial^2 t}$. Using the method of separation we assume a solution will be $u(x,t)=\phi(x)G(t)$. After differentiating and substituting $u(x,t)$ into the PDE and separating we have two ODEs to solve,

$\frac{dG}{dt}=-\lambda kG$ and $\frac{d\phi^2}{d^2t}=\lambda\phi$

Both ODEs are solved using the exponential solution $e^{rt}$. This provides us with,

$G(t)=e^{-\lambda kt}$ and $\phi(x)=e^{\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$

My textbook goes onto state that $\phi(x)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+c_2 \sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$ because $\cos \sqrt{\lambda}$ and $\sin\sqrt{\lambda}$ are linear combinatins of $e^{\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$. This is the step I don't understand.

Using Eurler's formula, we should have, $e^{\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}x}=\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$. How does the imaginary constant vanish? Every resource I find keeps telling me this step is "obvious" but it isn't for me.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the ODE

$$
\frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2} - \lambda \phi = 0\\
(\frac{d^2}{dt^2} - \lambda ) \phi = 0\\
\mathcal{L} \equiv (\frac{d^2}{dt^2} - \lambda )\\
\mathcal{L} \phi = 0
$$

$\phi_+ \equiv e^{i\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ and $\phi_- \equiv e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ are solutions to the ODE which is to say $\mathcal{L}(\phi_{\pm})=0$. The ODE is linear so if you take any combination $\alpha \phi_+ + \beta \phi_-$ and plug in into the ODE you get

$$
\mathcal{L} (\alpha \phi_+ + \beta \phi_-) = \alpha \mathcal{L} (\phi_+) + \beta \mathcal{L} (\phi_-)\\
= \alpha 0 + \beta 0 = 0\\
$$

to say that is also a solution. It does not matter what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are.

So therefore $\frac{1}{2} \phi_+ + \frac{1}{2} \phi_-$ is a solution as well. This is by taking $\alpha = \beta = \frac{1}{2}$. But this expression just gives $\cos \sqrt{\lambda} x$.

Using different coefficients $\alpha,\beta$, $\frac{1}{2i} \phi_+ - \frac{1}{2i} \phi_-$ is a solution as well. But this expression just gives $\sin \sqrt{\lambda} x$.

Now that we know both $\cos$ and $\sin$ are solutions we can take linear combinations of those with coefficents $c_1$ and $c_2$. Use the same argument with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but using $c_1$ and $c_2$ and making them coefficents of $\cos$ and $\sin$ instead of $\phi_{\pm}$. It does not matter how these are written as linear combinations of $\phi_{\pm}$ but you can do the substitutions through if you want to figure out how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ correspond to $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Okay. I believe I understand. Because for all constants $\alpha , \beta$ , $\alpha e^{i\sqrt{\lambda} x}+\beta ​e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ when expanded always provides $c_1 \cos \sqrt{\lambda} x$ and $\alpha e^{i\sqrt{\lambda} x}-\beta ​e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ always provides $c_2 \sin \sqrt{\lambda} x$, we can state that $\phi(x)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+c_2 \sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$ due to the verification that $e^{\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$ always satisfies the linearity property.

Answer (score 0):

You have both $$\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$$ and $$ \cos \sqrt{\lambda}x-i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$$ solutions to a linear homogenous  differential equation so you can add and subtract these two solutions to get a new solution.

Thus  we have $$\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x+
\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x-i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x =2\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x $$ and  $$\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x-
\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x =2i\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x $$
as solutions.

Dividing by the constants we get two linearly independent real  solutions so we can find the general solution.$$\phi(x)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+c_2 \sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$$